# sorting list of files by size is taking too much time

Tags: java, android, sorting

sorting list of folders is working well but it's take too much time and makes the phone freezes until the method finish.
this is the method I use to sort the files list

```
public static void sortFromLargeToSmall(List<Folders> foldersList, SDCardListViewAdapter sdCardListViewAdapter) {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Folders folder: foldersList)
        files.add(folder.getFile());
    Comparator<File> sizeFileComparator = SizeFileComparator.SIZE_SUMDIR_REVERSE;
    Collections.sort(files, sizeFileComparator);
    sdCardListViewAdapter.clear();
    for(File file: files)
        if(file.isDirectory())
            sdCardListViewAdapter.add(new Folders(R.drawable.ic_folders, file.getName(), file));
        else
            sdCardListViewAdapter.add(new Folders(R.drawable.ic_file, file.getName(), file));
}
```

and this the folder object constructor

```
public Folders(int imageView, String folderName, File file) {
    this.folderIcon = imageView;
    this.folderName = folderName;
    this.file = file;
    this.isSelected = false;
    foldersPath = new ArrayList<>();
    foldersName = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

is there a way to make the method very quick and don't make the phone freeze

Comment: Making it *very quick* is quite broad, but to stop the UI thread from being blocked for too long you could run this on a background thread.

Comment: Use the IDE's performance analysis tools, or even `Log` statements, to determine *exactly* where in your code your time is being spent.

Comment: Sort foldersList directly. Dont use an intermediate list. Further you did not post comparator code. You do not have to create new Folders then either. Add a size variable to your Folders class which you use for comparator.